# Getting SIGSEGV/SIGABRT when allocating memory for a string

Tags: c++, string, malloc, new-operator

Really don't know what to make of this--my program keeps crashing when I am allocating memory for a string, most often in this innocuous bit of code, which in other contexts has never caused a problem:

```
template <class T>
inline string to_string (const T& t, bool use_fixed = false)
{
    stringstream ss;
    if (use_fixed) ss.setf(ios::fixed, ios::floatfield);
    ss << t;
    return ss.str();
}
```

Specifically it crashes at 'ss << t'.  t was type int, ==0. The last lines of the stack trace look like this (alas, I'm too new to post a screenshot):

```
0   ??  
1   malloc
2   operator new(unsigned int)
3   std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned int, unsigned int, std::allocator<char> const&)
4   std::string::_Rep::_M_clone(std::allocator<char> const&, unsigned int)
5   std::string::reserve(unsigned int)
6   std::basic_stringbuf<char, std::char_traits<char>, std:allocator<char> >::overflow(int)
...
```

The only possibly relevant thing different with my program now that I can think of is that it has multiple threads, and launches a child process which has multiple threads and also calls this function. I'm on Ubuntu 10.04.  Thanks for your consideration--

Matt

Comment: Is it possible for you to post a full stack trace?  It's hard to say what's going on without more context.  It's also entirely possible that the bug involved has nothing to do with the code where it's manifesting itself.  My guess is that there's an overrun of array bounds somewhere.  You might try running your program in Valgrind or DUMA to see what you come up with.

Comment: Unfortunately a full stack trace isn't feasible until my reputation >= 10 and I can post a screenshot. :)  I've never used valgrind before, I'll see about it.

Comment: Did  you figure out what was happening?

Comment: @highBandWidth No, I think the problem sort of disappeared on its own as I made other changes.  But with C++11 and `std::to_string` the issue is happily moot now.

Answer (score 5):

The standard answer when this happens is "you're corrupting the memory allocator internal data structures somehow", so that's why it crashes. Check your array bounds because if you write outside the bonds of a memory block, you might overwrite something that you shouldn't.

Comment: Right.  But how could I be doing that?  An example where this has just happened with strings (though not to_string) is void MyClass::Member { string str; ... str = "here's a string"; }, with a crash on the assignment. str is local, is not shadowing anything.

Comment: Pretty simple: char *p = new char[2]; p[2] = 'c'; This is writing where it shouldn't be.

Comment: I'm using std::string, not char*.  The STL is doing all the allocation.  So how could I be getting the STL to screw up?

Answer (score 3):

Actually Matias Valdenegro gave you the correct answer. However, he did it in a way, that you didn't understand it: He said that you're corrupting the memory allocator's internal data structures somehow. And that's exactly what you were doing. The only thing *you* didn't understand (and Matias didn't tell you): You're not corrupting the heap in the code you've quoted here. You're corrupting the heap somewhere *else*. The quoted code just triggers the abort signal, because that's the point where the allocator functions (i.e. the new operator) *detects*, that your heap got corrupted (somewhere else). And that's exactly why - in opposite to your comment - C++'es std::to_string won't help here at all (it will also SIGABRT if you corrupt the heap) and it's why the bug suddenly disappeared, while you were working on something else elsewhere. You obviously just fixed the bug causing the heap corruption in the first place.

A great tool to find this kind of bug is called valgrind, if you don't know about it yet, you most certainly should change that because it would have told you not only what's going on, but also, where the actual bug resides.